# ¿Como permitir al usuario redimensionar una label despues de crearla en Java?

Tags: java

Estoy creando un editor de etiquetas, el cual consta de un `panel` que es donde se cargan los `label`, estos pueden contener texto o imágenes, una vez creados me gustaría que el usuario pueda redimensionarlos.

Ya tengo las demás funciones (moverlo de posición, etc.), esta es la única funcion que me falta mas no encuentro una manera de hacerlo, así es como se mira mi programa:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que quiero lograr hacer con los `label` creados:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Postea todo tu codigo del programa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una buena aproximación es implementar los eventos del raton sobre el componente identificando en que area del JLabel se esta moviendo y luego 'jugar' con los tipos de cursores; Te compartiré el núcleo del código que escribí para cambiar tamaños con el mouse.

```
    Cursor CD = new Cursor( Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR );
    Cursor C1 = new Cursor( Cursor.NW_RESIZE_CURSOR );
    Cursor C2 = new Cursor( Cursor.SW_RESIZE_CURSOR );
    Cursor C3 = new Cursor( Cursor.NE_RESIZE_CURSOR );
    Cursor C4 = new Cursor( Cursor.SE_RESIZE_CURSOR );
    Cursor C5 = new Cursor( Cursor.W_RESIZE_CURSOR );
    Cursor C6 = new Cursor( Cursor.E_RESIZE_CURSOR );
    Cursor C7 = new Cursor( Cursor.N_RESIZE_CURSOR );
    Cursor C8 = new Cursor( Cursor.S_RESIZE_CURSOR );
    int espacio = 4, tamMin = 30;

    etiqueta.addMouseMotionListener( new MouseMotionAdapter() {
      public void mouseMoved( MouseEvent evt ) {
        if( evt.getX() <= espacio && evt.getY() <= espacio ) {
          etiqueta.setCursor( C1 );// Sobre los bordes superior/izquierdo
        } else if( evt.getX() <= espacio && evt.getY() >= etiqueta.getHeight() - espacio ) {
          etiqueta.setCursor( C2 );// Sobre los bordes inferior/izquierdo
        } else if( evt.getY() <= espacio && evt.getX() >= etiqueta.getWidth() - espacio ) {
          etiqueta.setCursor( C3 );// Sobre los bordes superior/derecho
        } else if( evt.getY() >= etiqueta.getHeight() - espacio && evt.getX() >= etiqueta.getWidth() - espacio ) {
          etiqueta.setCursor( C4 );// Sobre los bordes inferior/derecho
        } else if( evt.getX() <= espacio ) {
          etiqueta.setCursor( C5 );// Sobre el borde izquierdo
        } else if( evt.getX() >= etiqueta.getWidth() - espacio ) {
          etiqueta.setCursor( C6 );// Sobre el borde derecho
        } else if( evt.getY() <= espacio ) {
          etiqueta.setCursor( C7 );// Sobre el borde superior
        } else if( evt.getY() >= etiqueta.getHeight() - espacio ) {
          etiqueta.setCursor( C8 );// Sobre el borde inferior
        } else {
          etiqueta.setCursor( CD );// Ninguno de los bordes
        }
      }

      public void mouseDragged( MouseEvent evt ) {
        // captura del tipo de cursor
        int tipoCursor = etiqueta.getCursor().getType();

        switch( tipoCursor ) {
          case 4: // Tipo SouthWest [esquina inferior izquierda]
               if( etiqueta.getWidth() > tamMin && etiqueta.getHeight() > tamMin ) {
                 etiqueta.setSize( etiqueta.getWidth() - evt.getX(), etiqueta.getHeight() - ( etiqueta.getHeight() - evt.getY() ) );
                 etiqueta.setLocation( etiqueta.getX() + evt.getX(), etiqueta.getY() );
               }
          break;
          case 5: // Tipo SouthEast [esquina inferior derecha]
               if( etiqueta.getWidth() > tamMin && etiqueta.getHeight() > tamMin ) {
                 etiqueta.setSize( etiqueta.getWidth() - ( etiqueta.getWidth() - evt.getX() ), etiqueta.getHeight() - ( etiqueta.getHeight() - evt.getY() ) );
                 etiqueta.setLocation( etiqueta.getX(), etiqueta.getY() );
               }
          break;
          case 6: // Tipo NorthWest [esquina superior izquierda]
               if( etiqueta.getWidth() > tamMin && etiqueta.getHeight() > tamMin ) {
                 etiqueta.setSize( etiqueta.getWidth() - evt.getX(), etiqueta.getHeight() - evt.getY() );
                 etiqueta.setLocation( etiqueta.getX() + evt.getX(), etiqueta.getY() + evt.getY() );
               }
          break;
          case 7: // Tipo NorthEast [esquina superior derecha]
               if( etiqueta.getWidth() > tamMin && etiqueta.getHeight() > tamMin ) {
                 etiqueta.setSize( etiqueta.getWidth() - ( etiqueta.getWidth() - evt.getX() ), etiqueta.getHeight() - evt.getY()  );
                 etiqueta.setLocation( etiqueta.getX(), etiqueta.getY() + evt.getY() );
               }
          break;
          case 8: // Tipo North [borde superior]
               if( etiqueta.getHeight() > tamMin ) {
                 etiqueta.setSize( etiqueta.getWidth(), etiqueta.getHeight() - evt.getY() );
                 etiqueta.setLocation( etiqueta.getX(), etiqueta.getY() + evt.getY() );
               }
          break;
          case 9: // Tipo South [borde inferior]
               if( etiqueta.getHeight() > tamMin ) {
                 etiqueta.setSize( etiqueta.getWidth(), etiqueta.getHeight() - ( etiqueta.getHeight() - evt.getY() ) );
                 etiqueta.setLocation( etiqueta.getX(), etiqueta.getY() );
               }
          break;
          case 10: // Tipo West [borde izquierdo]
               if( etiqueta.getWidth() > tamMin ) {
                 etiqueta.setSize( etiqueta.getWidth() - evt.getX(), etiqueta.getHeight() );
                 etiqueta.setLocation( etiqueta.getX() + evt.getX(), etiqueta.getY() );
               }
          break;
          case 11: // Tipo East [borde derecho]
               if( etiqueta.getWidth() > tamMin ) {
                 etiqueta.setSize( etiqueta.getWidth() - ( etiqueta.getWidth() - evt.getX() ), etiqueta.getHeight() );
                 etiqueta.setLocation( etiqueta.getX(), etiqueta.getY() );
               }
          break;
        }

        actualizarDimension();
      }
    } );
    etiqueta.addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter() {
      public void mouseReleased( MouseEvent evt ) {
        if( etiqueta.getWidth() <= tamMin ) {
          etiqueta.setBounds( etiqueta.getX(), etiqueta.getY(), etiqueta.getWidth() - ( etiqueta.getWidth() - ( tamMin + 1 ) ), etiqueta.getHeight() );
        }

        if( etiqueta.getHeight() <= tamMin ) {
          etiqueta.setBounds( etiqueta.getX(), etiqueta.getY(), etiqueta.getWidth(), etiqueta.getHeight() - ( etiqueta.getHeight() - ( tamMin + 1 ) ) );
        }

        actualizarDimension();
      }
    } );
    componentes.add( etiqueta );
  }

  public void actualizarDimension() {
    int W = etiqueta.getWidth() == 0 ? 1 : etiqueta.getWidth();
    int H = etiqueta.getHeight() == 0 ? 1 : etiqueta.getHeight();
    Image image = new ImageIcon( getClass().getResource( "/images/crash.jpeg" ) ).getImage();
    image = image.getScaledInstance( W, H, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH );
    etiqueta.setIcon( new ImageIcon( image ) );
    info.setText( "Dimension [" + etiqueta.getWidth() + "*" + etiqueta.getHeight() + " pixeles]  Posicion Ejes X:Y [" + etiqueta.getX() + ":" + etiqueta.getY() + "]" );
  }
```

Lógicamente puedes mejorar el anterior snippet agregando, sacando y optimizando alguna característica que veas.

[image: Crash Bandicoot]

Comment: Muchas gracias esto era lo que necesitaba

Comment: Disculpa @Johnny y para rotar las `JLabel` igual en tiempo de ejecución no sabes alguna manera de como hacerlo?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar a, en el constructor del label, poner `setResizable(true);`, creando una clase para el label en cuestión que extienda de JLabel.